# Rake Task not inserting into database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, rake-task

I have a ruby on rails application where I need to run a rake task which will hit the twitterstream api and insert tweets from a certain location into a database. For this I created a table called uncat_tweets. My rake task looks like this

```
task :get_uncat_tweets => :environment do
  TweetStream.configure do |c|
    ...
    ...
  end

  puts "#{UncatTweets.count}

  client = TweetStream::Client.new()
  client.locations(coordinates) do |status|
    puts "#{status.text}"
    t = UncatTweets.new()
    t.text = status.text
    t.long = ...
    t.lat = ...
    t.time = ....
    t.save!
  end
```

My uncat_tweets model looks like this:

```
class UncatTweets < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :lat, :long, :text, :time, :user
end
```

When i run rake get_uncat_tweets the tweetstream works and spews out tweets. But the rake task is not pushing to the database. The line `puts "#{UncatTweets.count}"` returns. I went  to the rails console and tried inserting a dummy value of UncatTweets and it worked! But when I run the rake task the program proceeds without error but never pushes into the database. Whats happening here? I am unable to find a solution to this problem.
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is Rails 3, you should follow the Rails 3 method for doing this.

First, open up `db/seeds.rb` in your Rails app. Set it up like so (based on your rake task above):

```
TweetStream.configure do |c|
  ...
  ...
end

puts "Number of tweets: #{UncatTweets.count}"

client = TweetStream::Client.new()

# Note you will have to define the following variable "coordinates" somewhere
client.locations(coordinates) do |status|
  UncatTweets.create(:text => status.text, :long => ..., :lat => ..., :time => ...)
end
```

and then run it by doing `rake db:seed`